# Why must the field $K$ be ordered in the Inertia Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordered-fields

Page 11 of "Linear Algebra and Geometry" by Irving Kaplansky

---

Theorem 8: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over an ordered field $K$. Then $V$ can be written as an orthogonal direct sum $V= W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus W_3$, where the inner product is positive definite on $W_1$, negative definited on $W_2$ and identically zero on $W_3$. In such a decomposition the dimensions of $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ are uniquely determined.

---

Is there any obvious reason why the $K$ must be ordered for this theorem to hold? I mean, do the ideas of positive definite and negative definite make sense in an unordered field? I think so, you can still know which elements are negative and which are positive even if the field is not ordered, right? The fact that $K$ is ordered never appears in the proof of Theorem 8.

Comment: In that book the order is used in the paragraph before the theorem, to prove the first part. However, one can work also with a [prepositive cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Positive_cone). See Lam "Orderings, valuations, and quadratic forms" the part about [Witt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem). Possibly also in his "Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields".

Comment: Is $i \in \mathbb C$ positive or negative?

Comment: @plop I'm not seeing where the fact that $K$ is ordered ever is used. We are given an orthogonal basis $\{u_1,..,u_n\}$ and $<u_i,u_i>=b_i$ and then we arrange the $b_i's$ so that $b_1,..,b_r$ are positive etc. When do we ever use the fact that $K$ is ordered?

Comment: @MutatedPenguin The $b_i$ are in $K$. Note that when you have the positive elements you require that whatever that collection is is closed by sums, multiplications and by multiplication by squares.

Comment: Yeah, but $K$ was already ordered before we labeled them $b_1,...,b_r$. The indices are just labels, so this isn't usnig the fact that $K$ is ordered, right?

Comment: You are saying something really strange. You agree that $K$ was already ordered and are asking if they are using that it is ordered? It is right there in what you just said. The order is what allows you to classify those elements as positive, negative or zero. Now, that is what they are using. They could have got a similar result with less. Instead of an ordered field (equivalently a field together with a positive cone), but only having a pre-positive cone.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the ordering of the field $K$ with the order in which the elements $b_i$ are listed?

Comment: "The order is what allows you to classify those elements as positive, negative, or zero". That's what I needed to hear. I thought you might be able to have positive/negative and zero without necessarily having an ordering on the entire field.